# Can't figure out how to flatten further nests in JSON for output to CSV

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

As the title suggests, I am currently pulling from the OpenCorporate API some JSON text. I then take this, place it into a dataframe, and then output that dataframe to a CSV.

I am running into issues in the CSV where, for example, under "previous_names" and "industry_codes" I receive further nested JSON text.

i.e. when I search for "Sony" using my code, I receive under "previous names" column in my CSV the output

```
[{'company_name': 'SONY DADC NEW MEDIA SOLUTIONS AUSTRALIA PTY     LTD', 'start_date': '2015-03-10', 'end_date': '2017-07-02'}]
```

Here is my code as it is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

count = int(input("Please enter the number of queries you wish to perform."))
iteration = 0

while iteration < count:
    string = input("Please enter search terms.")
    string.replace(" ", "+")

    json_data = requests.get('https://api.opencorporates.com/companies/search?q=' + string).json()

    df = None
    for row in json_data["results"]["companies"]:
        if df is None:
            df = json_normalize(row["company"])
        else:
            df = pd.concat([df, json_normalize(row["company"])], sort=False)    

    string.replace("+", " ")
    df.to_csv(string + '.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    iteration += 1

print("Thank you, your queries have been performed.")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might want to take a look at this package: https://github.com/amirziai/flatten

Comment: Flattening row["company"] seems to have helped, thanks

Comment: can you post the json file